# Group by month and year when date in string format in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, date, group-by, aggregate, pymongo

The date in my collection is in string format. I am trying to group values by month and year. I have tried `$toDate` and `$dateFromString`. When I try `$month` and `$year`, I am getting some `1` for month and random year for the year.

I don't know what I should do next. How do I group by month and year?

This is my code:

```
db.hb_data.aggregate([{
$match: {
    date: {$exists: true}
}
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: {date: "$date"},
        video_starts:{$sum: '$video_starts'}
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        month: { $month: new Date("$_id.date") } ,
        year: { year: new Date("$_id.date") } ,
        date: "$_id.date",
        video_starts: '$video_starts'
}   }
])
```

This is my result:

[My result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbHWZ.png)

How do I get the sum by month and year when my date is in a string format?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose this is the data set.

```
[
  {"Id_Cust": "4145","firstName": "Albade","lastName": "Maazou", "gender": "female","date": "21/03/1981"},
  {"Id_Cust": "5296", "firstName": "Rafael","lastName": "Oliveira","gender": "male","date": "08/06/1987"},
  {"Id_Cust": "6192","firstName": "Abdul Rahman","lastName": "Budjana","gender": "male","date": "26/01/1990"}
]
```

You can do it by using `$dateFromString` in the following way:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      month: {
        $month: {
          $dateFromString: {
            dateString: "$date",
            format: "%d/%m/%Y"
          }
        }
      },
      year: {
        $year: {
          $dateFromString: {
            dateString: "$date",
            format: "%d/%m/%Y"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },

])
```

**Output:**

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "month": 3,
    "year": 1981
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
    "month": 6,
    "year": 1987
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),
    "month": 1,
    "year": 1990
  }
]
```

**Update**

You can also do it using `$toDate` but your String Date format should be  `"yyyy-mm-dd"` format e.g `{$toDate:  "2018-03-03"}`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      month: {
        $month: {
          $toDate: "$date"
        }
      },
      year: {
        $year: {
          $toDate: "$date"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

It gives exactly same output as above **but make sure your String Date is in `"yyyy-mm-dd"` this format.**

Comment: I am getting a `"Unrecognized expression '$dateFromString'"` error.

Comment: Which version of mongo you are using ?

Comment: I am using 3.4.9

Comment: '$dateFromString' is supported from 3.6 only.

Comment: Check the update part you can also do this using `$toDate`

Comment: Is this problem fixed with the solution I provided ?

Comment: Not really. I used `$month` and `$year` inside the `$group` and then it worked. If I didnt need to use an older version of Mongo I am sure your solution would've worked.